# Access denied on core creation via Solr 8.8 admin ui

Tags: solr

I'm struggling with Apache solr 8.8 core configuration.
I've got core configuration files ready (generated by Drupal 9 Search API solr module).

Then I tried to put these files there `solr/cores/drupal_core` and there `solr/current/server/solr/cores/drupal_core`

When I go to the UI I try to create new core but I've got an access denied...

[image: access denied on core creation via solr admin ui]

I'm not sure to understand. I've tried to change permissions on core folders, but nothing is working... Has someone some idea of what is happening ?

Comment: Check the Solr log - it'll give you details about what's actually happening. The console will only show what the API responded with (and the angular messages).